# Differences in the liturgy between Novus Ordo and the Anglican Use (2013)?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, anglican-ordinariate

In 2009 Pope Benedict XVI established [personal ordinariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_ordinariate) structure for Anglican groups wishing to join the Catholic Church while retaining elements of their "liturgical and spiritual patrimony".  In 2013, the [Divine Worship: The Missal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Worship:_The_Missal) was promulgated to replace the [Book of Divine Worship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Divine_Worship), an earlier Catholic adaptation of the [Book of Common Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Common_Prayer).

My question is for the difference between the [*Novus Ordo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_of_Paul_VI) (Ordinary Form) liturgy that most Catholic parishes use and the 2013 "Anglican use" version.  To prevent the answer to become unwieldy, the answer can limit itself only for the regular Sunday mass so it doesn't have to cover weddings, funeral, Easter or Christmas liturgies, although more is welcome !

Answer (score 3):

**Differences in the liturgy between Novus Ordo and the Anglican Use (2013)?**

The liturgy is almost identical with the current Roman Rite liturgical calendar of the dioceses of England and Wales, but it has retained some elements that form part of the Anglican patrimony, as well as some of the liturgy of the Extraordinary Form of the Mass.

For example like in the Extraordinary Form, the prologue to John’s Gospel is read at the end of Sunday Mass, a little throwback to the Tridentine Mass.

The **sign of peace** is placed after the act of contrition near the beginning of the mass.

> The placement of the kiss of peace was once of my favorite things about this liturgy. It followed an act of contrition, so the act of offering peace to our neighbor stemmed directly from expressing our sorrow to God. It made the handshakes feel more like an effort at reconciliation than a coffee break, the way they often do in the Novus Ordo. And this reconciliation is just as tied to approaching the altar when placed right before the consecration as it is right before communion. I think moving it earlier also helps me stay focused from the Sanctus all the way through communion, rather than taking a break from prayer to chat before the Agnus Dei. - [The Anglican Use Mass](https://www.piercedhands.com/the-anglican-use-mass/)

Although national episcopal conferences may retain the usage of Ember Days and Rogation Days, none have opted to do so. The Anglican Use has decided to do so.

> The proper liturgical calendar of the ordinariate was approved by the Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the Sacraments on 15 February 2012. In the main, it is identical with the current Roman Rite liturgical calendar of the dioceses of England and Wales, but it has retained some elements that form part of the Anglican patrimony.
>
> In the Proper of Time:
>
> [Ember Days](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ember_days) are observed on the Wednesday, Friday and Saturday after the First Sunday of Lent, Pentecost (Whit-Sunday), Holy Cross Day and the First Sunday of Advent.
>
> [Rogation Days](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogation_days#Minor_Rogations) are observed on the three days following the Sixth Sunday of Easter.
>
> In the week between Pentecost and Trinity Sunday, elements of the former octave are fostered: while the readings of the Ordinary Time weekday are retained, the Mass propers and use of red as the liturgical colour "may sustain the themes of Pentecost".
>
> - [Personal Ordinariate of Our Lady of Walsingham](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Ordinariate_of_Our_Lady_of_Walsingham)

They have also preserved the use of the subdeacons on certain days.

> In the Solemn High Mass form of Tridentine Mass and the Ordinariate Mass, the duties of a subdeacon included those of crucifer, singing the Epistle, holding the Book of Gospels while the deacon sings the Gospel, carrying it back to the celebrant afterwards and assisting the priest or deacon in setting the altar. - [Subdeacon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdeacon)

Masses are ***ad orientem*** and communion is distributed kneeling down. This again is also permitted in the ***Novus Ordo***.

[image]

The [vestments](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasuble) tend to be universally fiddlebacks in the Anglican Usage of the Roman Rite.